# Apache mod_proxy on Azure

Tags: apache, azure, ssl, apache2, playframework-2.1

I keep running into an issue with Apache's mod_proxy where it won't forward any traffic.  I'm using a Windows Azure virtual machine running Ubuntu 13.04 and have configured the proper HTTPS endpoint (port 443) for it.  The proper Apache modules (proxy, ssl, etc.) are all installed, and the error logs show nothing, not even a warning to explain why this is happening.  My VirtualHost setup is as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    ServerName www.example.com

    SSLEngine On
    #SSLProxyEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /ssl/my.com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /ssl/my.key
    <Proxy *>
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    <Location />
            SSLRequireSSL
  Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
    </Location>

    ProxyPass /  http://127.0.0.1:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
     </VirtualHost>
```

I have `Listen 443` and `NameVirtualHost *:443` all set as well.  My service on the other port is running fine as doing a `wget` responds with an HTTP 200 OK response and I can reach it by manually inputting the port number.  I have disabled all firewalls (for testing) to no avail as well.  However, whenever I try to reach the service from the outside world through mod_proxy (port 443), the request times out and I get the usual "website not available" browser error.

If it means anything, the app I am running on the other port I need to forward HTTPS traffic to is a Play Framework 2.1 application.  I set the server up exactly as in their documentation but still have these problems, so I'm assuming it may have something to do with Azure.

Any ideas? Is there some other type of endpoint configuration that I need to do specific for Windows Azure virtual machines to support SSL/TLS?

Comment: As you can tell from the VirtualHost example, I tried about a dozen different suggestions from all over the internet already - none of them worked, so I'm hoping someone here has had this issue before perhaps.

Comment: Also, this issue is not limited to just HTTPS - HTTP (port 80) traffic doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, apparently, I have no idea how or why - but the Azure Gods decided to shine upon my setup all of a sudden.  Overnight, without so much as a reboot or anything, mod_proxy on Azure just started working.  I have no idea what the issue was, or even if there was one in the first place, but apparently the problem lies with something in the Azure infrastructure.

Sorry I couldn't be of more help for others encountering similar issues, but just giving it time worked for some unknown reason.